# Expected view to be called with a URL keyword argument named "user_token"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and here is my view:

```
class DeleteUserView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user_token'
```

and my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import CreateUserView, DeleteUserView

urlpatterns = [
    path('add_user/', CreateUserView.as_view()),
    path('delete_user/', DeleteUserView.as_view()),
]
```

serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_token',)
```

I am trying to delete user by specific token but it doesn't work...I am using Postman and provide `user_token` in Body

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post the request URL you used in Postman here?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Expected view DeleteUserView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "user_token". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh here is the request url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_user/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `lookup_field` paremeter, it basically looks for that variable in your URLconfig. Eg.

```
path('delete_user/(?P<user_token>[-\w]+)/', DeleteUserView.as_view()),
```

If you specify the URL like above, and then call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_user/1/`, it should work

**Note**

In Your case, if you are going to have CRUD views like `add_user`, `delete_user`, `update_user`, then I suggest you use a [model viewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)